Simulating bias comparing linear regression with Cox Proportional Hazard model for prediction on censored data
I wanted to show how censoring biases linear regression and how that could be resolved with survival regression using simulated data. My simulation now suggests, that survival regression (I tried a Cox Proportional Hazard model) results in a smaller but still existent bias than linear regression. So I either did something wrong in the simulation, misunderstood how survival analysis helps with predicting on data with censoring, or how to simulate bias due to censoring.
Here is the python code for the simulation, adapted from the lifelines documentation:
def simulate_data(n, observed_periods):
    age = np.random.randint(18, 80, n)
    start = np.random.randint(0, observed_periods, n)
    stop = start + np.random.binomial(age, 0.3, n)
    actual_lifetimes = stop - start
    observed_lifetimes = np.minimum(stop, observed_periods) - start
    death_observed = actual_lifetimes < observed_periods
    data = pd.DataFrame(age, columns=['age'])
    data['lifetime'] = observed_lifetimes
    data['actual_lifetime'] = actual_lifetimes
    data['observed'] = death_observed
    data['observed'] = data['observed'].astype(int)
    return data

lin_preds = []
surv_preds = []
for i in range(1000):
    data = simulate_data(100000, 10)
    data_train, data_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(data_train[['age']], data_train['lifetime'])
    data_test['predicted_lifetime'] = reg.predict(data_test[['age']])
    data_test['predicted_lifetime'] = np.maximum(data_test['predicted_lifetime'], 0)
    data_test['error'] = data_test['predicted_lifetime'] - data_test['actual_lifetime']
    lin_preds.append(data_test['error'].mean())

    cph = CoxPHFitter()
    cph.fit(data_train[['lifetime', 'observed', 'age']], duration_col='lifetime', event_col='observed', fit_options = {'step_size': 0.5})
    data_test['predicted_lifetime_cph'] = cph.predict_expectation(data_test)
    data_test['error_cph'] = data_test['predicted_lifetime_cph'] - data_test['actual_lifetime']
    surv_preds.append(data_test['error_cph'].mean())
    
print("Linear Regression Mean Error: ", np.mean(lin_preds), " and Varaince: ", np.var(lin_preds))
print("Cox Proportional Hazards Mean Error: ", np.mean(surv_preds), " and Varaince: ", np.var(surv_preds))

which results in
Linear Regression Mean Error:  -9.257568636025532  and Varaince:  0.002010272567626195
Cox Proportional Hazards Mean Error:  -6.135654283086111  and Varaince:  0.006220225461769601

So in this example it seams like the survival model only revokers some of the bias. Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to remove all bias, when censoring is correlated with long lifetimes?
sidenote: in the simulation there were on average around 35% censored cases

In some brief simulations, it seems that you have a lot of observed_lifetimes at the minimum possible value of 1. With your modeling of the association of log-hazard and age strictly linear, that leads to a violation of the proportional hazards (PH) assumption underlying a Cox model. That can be alleviated by a more flexible fit of age, e.g. with a regression spline. I'm also not sure whether your formula for actual_lifetimes meets a PH assumption either, though I haven't thought that through.

thanks @EdM I adjusted the DGP and it changes the results. Nevertheless, a bias remains for both approaches. Is that how it is or is the DGP still wrong. I'm not sure I entirely understood you comment

It's important to check the assumptions an quality-of-fit of any regression model. In lifelines, see this page for testing the PH assumption of a Cox regression model. You might also want to do standard linear regression quality control on your linear regression model. If assumptions aren't met then it's hard to know what the estimated bias means.
